# How to correct render page Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel

First of all, I want to say that I'm using Laravel 5.1 and I'm new with Laravel.

I make notifications from the site that the user receives for various actions on the site to store in the database. But i have one problem with this.

When I click on the button, which processing using `$.post` and it is written that if the user clicks on the button, he should receive a notification in the site block `$('#notifications').html(data)` , but the site block, when i click on the button, removes all past notifications and becomes empty.

My function at controller:

```
Notify::create(
    [
    'id' => $last_id + 1,
    'user_id' => $this->user->id,
    'title' => 'Notification',
    'message' => 'Test '.Request::get('operation').'',
    'status' => '1',
    ]);
$user_notifications = \DB::table('notifications')->where('user_id', $this->user->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
return view('includes.notifications', compact('user_notifications'))->render();
```

My JS:

```
$('.calc-place').click(function () {
    var operation = $(this).attr('data-type');
        $.post('/getNotify', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#notifications').html(data)
        });
});
```

At browser console I have `__proto__: Object`.

[Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ0D3.png)

But this result not render at `<div id="#notifications">`.

Where is my problem? How I can fix this problem? If you need additional information, I am ready to provide.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using *$('#notifications').html(data)*, use *$('#notifications').append(data)*

Comment: it doen't help. i mean, notification's don't be empty, but notification at block doesn't update